# How do I spyOn third party function with jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am having trouble mocking a third party dependency. I'm always recieving this error:

> Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function;
>   undefined given instead

Here are the details of this issue. First, this is the function I am testing:

File: `src/js/mp_wrapper.js`

```js
import { Viewer } from 'third-party';

module.exports = {
    createViewer: container => {
        if (util.isElement(container)) {
            return new Viewer(container);
        } else {
            throw new Error(
                'Invalid Element when attempting to create underlying viewer.',
            );
        }
    },
}
```

Looking at the source code for my third-party, `Viewer` is very simple and looks like this:

```js
function Viewer(){
 // Doing things
}

Viewer.prototype.foo = function(){

}

module.exports = Viewer;
```

And finally, here is my test.

File: `/tests/mp_wrapper.spec.js`

```js
import { Viewer } from 'third-party`;
import mp_wrapper from '../src/js/mp_wrapper';

describe('mp_wrapper', () => {
    describe('createViewer', () => {
        test('returns a new instance of the Viewer class', () => {
            const spy = jest.spyOn(Viewer).mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
            // It fails on the line above... -> "Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function; undefined given instead"

            const testElement = document.createElement(testElement);
            let viewer = mp_wrapper.createViewer(testElement);

            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(viewer).toBeInstancecOf(Viewer);
            spy.mockRestore();
        });
    });
});
```

**How can I mock & spy on Viewer itself?**

I've done this in the past:

`const spy = jest.spyOn(Viewer.prototype, 'foo').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());`

I've also tried `default` with no luck:

`const spy = jest.spyOn(Viewer, 'default').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());`

But now I want to spy on Viewer.

**EDIT:**

This was my final solution. @brian-lives-outdoors answer is correct, but I didn't describe my problem accurately. The third party library I was trying to mock was slightly more complex because it export a module containing several constructors. It looked like this:

```
module.exports = {
  Viewer: require('./path/Viewer'),
  Foo: require('./foo_path/Foo'),
  Bar: require('./bar_path/Bar')
}
```

Then inside `./path/Viewer` is was as I previously described above.

Here's what my **solution** ended up looking like:

```js
import { Viewer } from 'lib';
import mp_wrapper from '../src/js/mp_wrapper';

jest.genMockFromModule('lib');
jest.mock('lib');

describe('mp_wrapper', () => {
    describe('createViewer', () => {
        test('returns a new instance of the Viewer class and sets the local _viewer property', () => {
            const testContainer = document.createElement('div');
            const viewer = mp_wrapper.createViewer(testContainer);
            expect(Viewer).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testContainer); // Success!
            expect(viewer).toBeInstanceOf(Viewer); // Success!
        });
    });
});
```

@brian-lives-outdoors What I don't understand is if I comment out the line `jest.mock('lib');` above, it doesn't work...Why?

Why isn't `genMockFromModule` sufficient by itself?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Any thoughts on this question? You seem to be an expert on mocking dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example code mixes ES6 `import`/ `export` syntax with Node `module.exports` syntax...

...but based on a library that looks like this:

**lib.js**

```
function Viewer() { }

Viewer.prototype.foo = function () { }

module.exports = Viewer;
```

...it would be used like this:

**mp_wrapper.js**

```
import Viewer from './lib';  // <= Babel allows Viewer to be used like an ES6 default export

export const createViewer = container => new Viewer(container);
```

...and to spy on `Viewer` you would need to mock the entire library in your test:

**mp_wrapper.spec.js**

```
import Viewer from './lib';
import { createViewer } from './mp_wrapper';

jest.mock('./lib', () => jest.fn());  // <= mock the library

test('returns a new instance of the Viewer class', () => {
  const viewer = createViewer('the container');
  expect(Viewer).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the container');  // Success!
  expect(viewer).toBeInstanceOf(Viewer);  // Success!
});
```

---

Note that if the library was an ES6 library then you could spy on the `default` export directly like this:

```
import * as lib from './lib';

const spy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'default');  // <= spy on the default export
```

...but because of the way Babel handles the interop between ES6 and non-ES6 code this approach doesn't work if the library is not ES6.

---

**Edit: response to the follow-up question**

[`jest.genMockFromModule`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestgenmockfrommodulemodulename) generates a mocked version of the module and returns it.

So for example this:

```
const mock = jest.genMockFromModule('lib');
```

...generates a mocked version of `lib` and assigns it to `mock`.  Note that this *does not* mean that the mock will be returned when `lib` is required during a test.

`jest.genMockFromModule` can be useful when creating a manual mock:

__mocks__/lib.js

```
const lib = jest.genMockFromModule('lib');  // <= generate a mock of the module
lib.someFunc.mockReturnValue('some value');  // <= modify it
module.exports = lib;  // <= export the modified mock
```

In your final solution you have these two lines:

```
jest.genMockFromModule('lib');
jest.mock('lib');
```

This line:

```
jest.genMockFromModule('lib');
```

...doesn't actually do anything since it is generating a mock of the module but the returned mock isn't being used for anything.

This line:

```
jest.mock('lib');
```

...tells `Jest` to auto-mock the `lib` module and is the only line that is needed in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your answer/help with this question. See my edit above for further solution and bonus question :-)

Comment: I just added an answer to the bonus question @calbear47

Comment: You are THE man! Thanks for the explanation. Absolutely helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

`util.js`

```js
const util = {
  isElement() {}
};

module.exports = util;
```

`View.js`, the third-party module:

```js
function Viewer() {
  // Doing things
  console.log('new viewer instance');
}

Viewer.prototype.foo = function() {};

module.exports = { Viewer };
```

`my_wrapper.js`:

```js
const { Viewer } = require('./viewer');
const util = require('./util');

module.exports = {
  createViewer: container => {
    if (util.isElement(container)) {
      return new Viewer(container);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Invalid Element when attempting to create underlying viewer.');
    }
  }
};
```

Unit test:

```js
const { Viewer } = require('./viewer');
const my_wrapper = require('./');
const util = require('./util');

jest.mock('./viewer', () => {
  return {
    Viewer: jest.fn()
  };
});

describe('mp_wrapper', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  describe('createViewer', () => {
    it('t1', () => {
      util.isElement = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(true);
      let viewer = my_wrapper.createViewer('el');
      expect(util.isElement).toBeCalledWith('el');
      expect(viewer).toBeInstanceOf(Viewer);
    });

    it('t2', () => {
      util.isElement = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(false);
      expect(() => my_wrapper.createViewer('el')).toThrowError(
        new Error('Invalid Element when attempting to create underlying viewer.')
      );
      expect(Viewer).not.toBeCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/57712713/index.spec.js
  mp_wrapper
    createViewer
      ✓ t1 (6ms)
      ✓ t2 (5ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |       50 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 util.js  |      100 |      100 |        0 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.134s, estimated 9s
```